# Splintering Jack stud - does it need replaced? or is there a way to mend it?

Tags: walls, repair, framing, load-bearing, window-frame

I could not find any solid answers about what to do with this scenario:
The jack stud on the left side of this window is split/splintered down the middle from what appears to be when the window was installed, So an exterior wall and perpendicular to the trusses (Correct terminology here? the ceiling joists parallel to gable ends)
Ever since we bought the house we have been fixing problems left and right, mostly due to water damage/possible termites as well (found the sources of the water infiltration and have since sealed and remedied the leaks) so the drywall is already gone and insulation replaced (they had originally R7 insulation?! ...In Michigan?!) which will most likely need to be taken back out because from all I've found online, the general big picture looks to be constructing a temporary wall and replacing both king and jack studs, and I don't really see any way around that myself but I am not a structural engineer or anything so I'm looking for input -
What would be the best way to go about fixing this? whether it be replacing the jack/king studs, or somehow repairing them?
[image: Window Wall][image: Top left corner][image: Left jack middle][image: clearer picture of split in jack stud]

Comment: The window seems to be screwed into the edge of wall sheathing instead of the jack stud. Unless maybe the jack stud is a 2x3 and there's another chunk of something pinched between the wall sheathing and the jack stud? If anything, I suspect that your window is incorrectly installed too far outside of the wall. What's going on outside with the siding and trim position relative to the face of the window? Judging by the R15 insulation, those are 2x4 walls, right?

Answer (score 1):

Those splinters do not affect the strength of that jack stud at all. Much worse can happen and it will still handle the load. If a moderate piece was missing or a large split was evident, that would be of concern, but the small chips you have there are of no concern.

Comment: Thank you for the response! The split I’m referring to is where the screws from the window are, not those chips at the end there - it’s a little hard to see in the picture but the split is down the majority of the jack stud

Comment: The crack, if it is that small, should not harm the integrity of the stud, Many times wood shrinks from the time it was cut and cracks like that. The crack when it is along the length of the stud, does very little to weaken it. If the crack is across the stud, it is a different matter. It also needs to be deep into the stud. Not only as deep a a screw would go.